# Change Tab Color upon opening a page C# Winforms Infragistics

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, .net-4.8

When a page is opened, it opens multiple tabs. I am trying to figure out how to change the ultraTab1 color to Red based on a condition? What should be the event trigger? The event should automatically change the color of the UltraTab1 to Red when the page is opened.

HomeDesigner.cs

```
Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTab ultraTab1 = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTab();
private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTabPageControl decorStyleTabPageControl;
this.decorStyleTabPageControl = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTabPageControl();
private Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraPanel decorStylePanel;
this.decorStylePanel = new Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraPanel();

ultraTab1.Key = "DecorStyle";
ultraTab1.TabPage = this.decorStyleTabPageControl;
ultraTab1.Text = "Decor Style";

this.decorStyleTabPageControl.Controls.Add(this.decorStylePanel);
this.decorStyleTabPageControl.Controls.Add(this.homeTabButtonPanel);
this.decorStyleTabPageControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-10000, -10000);
this.decorStyleTabPageControl.Name = "decorStyleTabPageControl";
this.decorStyleTabPageControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1051, 1051);
```

Condition as follows:

```
         if (e.Tab.Key == "DecorStyle")
         {
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    e.Tab.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
         }
```

Comment: https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawintabcontrol~infragistics.win.ultrawintabcontrol.ultratabcontrolbase~activetabchanged_ev

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a global variable in HomeDesigner.cs
2. Set it to true when the event SelectedTabChanged is triggered.
3. Loop the tab list and set the tab color for the required tab.

HomeDesigner.cs

```
var _decorStyleTabInitialized = false;

private async void mainTabControl_SelectedTabChanged(object sender, SelectedTabChangedEventArgs e){

    if(!_decorStyleTabInitialized){
        InitializeTabColor();
    }
}

private void InitializeTabColor(){
    var ultraTabCollection = this.decorStyleTabPageControl.Tabs;
    foreach(UltraTab tab in ultraTabCollection){
        if(tab.Key.Contains("DecorStyle")){
            SetTabColor(tab);
            _decorStyleTabInitialized = true;
        }
    }
}

private SetTabColor(UltraTab tab){
    tab.appearance.ForeColor = Color.White;
    tab.appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
    tab.appearance.BackColor2 = Color.Empty;
}
```